# Find $\lim_{x\to 0} \int_x^{x+1} \sqrt {\arctan {t}}\space dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \int_x^{x+1} \sqrt {\arctan {t}}\space dt$$

I think it does not exist because we can't talk about limit from $x\to 0^-$, but what if we just look for $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$? I see there less and less area of the graph so it should be $0$, but how we show it?

Comment: The limit from the right is $\int_0^1\sqrt{\arctan t}\,dt$. I know no closed form for that.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but in the answer they show it $\sqrt{\pi \over 4}$

Comment: @SammyBlack why you deleted your answer??? I liked it!

Comment: Maybe you are interested in the limit of $x\int_1^{1+x}\sqrt{\arctan t}\,dt$. Entirely different!

Comment: @AndréNicolas So the answer isn't right? Can we just prove that the limit exists?

Comment: As your question is currently typed, the limit from the left obviously exists. It is just the area under the curve from $0$ to $1$. In a comment, I suggested a different question, for which the answer is $\sqrt{\pi/4}$. By the way, as currently typed, the limit is not $\sqrt{\pi/4}$.

Comment: I was imagining it to be a FTC question like @AndréNicolas is suggesting, despite it *not quite being that.*  On autopilot, I hacked out an answer to the question that I imagined you were asking.  :-P

Comment: @SammyBlack so what's wrong with youe answer? because I don't see it :\ .

Comment: The derivative:  $F'(1) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} ( F(x+1) - F(1) )$.  Your limit is different:  $\lim_{x \to 0} ( F(x+1) - F(x) )$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas the function in the limit is continuous so the limit is - if we just put x=0 in it, right? so the limit exists.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Of course the limit from the left does not exist, for uninteresting reasons. (Earlier I had left-right interchanged.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\int_{0}^x \sqrt{\arctan t}dt$ Then, $$\lim_{x\to 0+}\int_{x}^{x+1}\sqrt{\arctan t}dt=\lim_{x\to 0+}(F(x+1)-F(x))\\=\lim_{x\to 0+}(F(x+1)-F(1))-\lim_{x\to 0+}(F(x)-F(0))+F(1)-F(0)\\=\int_{0}^1\sqrt{\arctan t}dt\\=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\theta}\sec^2\theta d\theta$$ I am not sure if this can be further simplified.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: I made a mistake, let me correct it.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning** : I wonder myself about the validity of my answer.

Suppose that we expand the integrand as a Taylor series around $t=0$ to get for the very first terms $$\sqrt{\tan ^{-1}(t)}=\sqrt{t}-\frac{t^{5/2}}{6}+\frac{31 t^{9/2}}{360}+O\left(t^{11/2}\right)$$Let us do that up to $n$ terms; integrate between $x$ and $x+1$ and expand the result as a Taylor series around $x=0$. Depending on $n$, the following limits would be obtained $$L_{(1)}=\frac 23$$ $$L_{(2)}=\frac{13}{21}$$ $$L_{(3)}=\frac{8797}{13860}$$ $$L_{(4)}=\frac{782237}{1247400}$$ $$L_{(5)}=\frac{39914989}{63201600}$$  $$L_{(6)}=\frac{16448621317}{26165462400}$$ $$L_{(7)}=\frac{810914558349223}{1285770822336000}$$ $$L_{(8)}=\frac{50156186947762121}{79717790984832000}$$ $$L_{(9)}=\frac{478368186036207277667}{758913370175600640000}$$which converge, rather slowly, to the numerical value of $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\tan ^{-1}(t)}\,dt$$ as Samrat Mukhopadhyay answered ($0.6298296269$, value for which inverse symbolic calculators did not find anything).

Answer (score 0):

We have an [integral of an inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions):
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\arctan t}\,dt &=&\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4}}-\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4}}}\tan(y^2)\,dy\\&=&\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4}}-\sqrt{\frac{4}{\pi}}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(4^k-1)(-1)^{k-1}B_{2k}}{(4k-1)(2k)!}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)^k\end{eqnarray*}$$
where we exploited the [Taylor series of the tangent function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentNumber.html), written in terms of Bernoulli numbers.